# Is it safe to use mysqldump to backup and restore a master-master cluster

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mariadb, galera, backup, xtrabackup

Not sure if the specifics matter but just to get it out of the way I am talking about a Galera cluster on XtraDB (MariaDB).

I have a master-master setup and am interested in backing up and restoring the database if necessary.  On a single instance of MySQL I do the run of the mill

```
 mysqldump -u USER -p DB_NAME > DB-DATE.sql

 -and to restore-

 mysql -u USER -p < /path/to/dump.sql
```

I am not sure how these commands will fare in a clustered environment.  I'm going to divide this into two parts with my comments in each:

**Backing up**

The only issue I can think of as far as backing up goes is during the backup process some data could be written to the cluster, a query happens, my backup runs, then another related query happens leaving my data in an inconsistent state.  Let's say I have two tables `users` and `counts`.  When a user submits a form a PHP script updates the users favorite color in `users` as well as increments a field in `counts` called `times_color_changed`.  This simple script may look like:

```
<?
    //Yes, these are vulnerable to SQL injection but this is to demonstrate a point.
    $query1 = "UPDATE `users` SET `favorite_color` = ".$_POST['color']." WHERE id = $user_id";
    $query2 = "UPDATE `counts` SET `times_color_changed`  = `times_color_changed` + 1 WHERE id = $user_id";
    mysql_query($query1);
    mysql_query($query2);
?>
```

My worry is that while running the `mysqldump` in parallel the queries run as follows:

```
 QUERY_1 runs
 MySQL_DUMP
 Query_2 runs

 -or-

 Query1 from remote server commits on local server
 MySQL_DUMP
 Query2 from remote server commits on local server
```

Either of these can lead to an inconstant state.  I could always stop the SQL server but then I can't run MySQL dump.

There is an `xtrabackup` command but I'm not familiar with it. I've always done my dumps through `mysqldump`

**Restoring**

When restoring my dump how can I be sure that this replicates to the remote server?  Will the cluster think my dump is the "old" data and not replicate it?

Comment: "Query1 from remote server commits on local server
 MySQL_DUMP
 Query2 from remote server commits on local server" This is not an inconsistent state. If you need q1 and q2 to be an atomic change then wrap it into a transaction. Now they're two different transactions.

Comment: what's the database size byte-wise?

Comment: @akuzminsky - Well it's de-facto atomic because we assume the entire script executes meaning both run.  This is how most PHP scripts are written... Do a query, calculate stuff, and do some more queries.  The DB is a few hundred MB

Comment: No. Atomic means begin-update-update-commit. In your example these are two different transactions. This might be not what you want, but one can't call this inconsistent state.

Comment: @akuzminsky Wow interesting point.  As a sysadmin I've killed a lot of PHP scripts and bounced apache a lot in my day.  I've never had issues with corrupt databases but could this theoretically leave the DB inconsistant?  Imagine a vBulletin forum where the person created a post but the script terminates before the post count is updated....  or is the MySQL engine smart enough to handle and recover from this?  I've never seen anyone care to begin\commit transactions even in commercial software and never thought this would be a problem.

Comment: Let's leave corrupt database aside to avoid further confusion. From ACID definitions: "The consistency property ensures that any transaction will bring the database from one valid state to another". Your two UPDATES bring database from state one valid state to another valid state - two times. So, the database is never inconsistent. What you're talking about is application-level inconsistency (I admit confusion in terminology). But that happens not because the database server failed to perform its job.

Comment: cont. ...but rather because the application doesn't work properly with the database. Thus no storage engine and no backup tool will help to fix flaws in the application logic. BTW, either tool will work fine.

Comment: @akuzminsky Gotcha.  Thanks for clearing that up.  So basically something can't "half-update", the update per ACID is guarenteed to go through.  We as developers tend to assume all the queries in a script execute.  I've never seen terminating a script cause this application level consistency but it seems theoretically possible, especially during multiple large transactions.

Comment: @wannabeedba We as developers must wherever possible NOT assume that all queries get run as the script could end part way through for many different reasons. My team uses transactions (begin, query, query, query, commit) wherever it makes sense to do so and you should to, for exactly the kind of reasons you are alluding to in your question. The fact that some commercial applications you mention are not well written doesn't mean yours shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly urge you to use [Percona's XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup). You're already using their storage engine - take the time to get to know this tool! Good reasons not to use mysqldump can be found [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/11/08/an-argument-for-not-using-mysqldump-in-production/). If you really have to get text file SQL dumps of your data, check out [mydumper](https://launchpad.net/mydumper), see [here](http://www.palominodb.com/blog/2011/08/02/mydumper-myloader-fast-backup-and-restore) and [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2014/03/10/new-mydumper-0-6-1-release-offers-several-performance-and-usability-features/) for why (disclaimer - haven't used).

Comment: I just feel safer using mysqldump since I have the actual raw SQL.  I plan on doing xtrabackups also but it's comforting to know I have a SQL file I can plop onto a database at any time.  Is there an issue with using mysqldump besides the speed (the inconsistent state issue I mentioned)

Comment: Check [this](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.5/features/highavailability.html) out - I know it's "nice" to have human readable backups, but perhaps leaving this (complicated) area in the hands of the experts is the best choice? The important bit in the link above is "the downside of mysqldump and rsync is that your cluster becomes READ-ONLY while data is being copied from one node to another" whereas Xtrabackup does not.

Comment: I'm not worried about taking down the database for a few minutes.  This will be done off hours.  If possible I could even pull a node offline, start it in "non-clustered" mode, and dump it.  Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but why not? You could test and see, but it strikes me that you're making extra (Xtra?) work for yourself when you have tools that will do the heavy lifting for you. Test and see.

Comment: Xtra lol.  Ok I will focus on xtrabackup.  However another commenter mentioned that my queries are not wrapped in a single transaction and thus are not atomic.  I am actually using ActiveRecord which does a ton of non-atomic queries.  Could xtrabackup theoretically get my data in an inconsistent state (since it does a hot backup) if a PHP script fires at the right time?  Would it be safer to pull the node offline first?

Comment: Knowing nothing about ActiveRecord, I can't honestly say what would happen. The best thing to do would be to ask [here](http://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/percona-xtrabackup) where you get replies from the guys who actually write the Xtra backup stuff - i.e. Percona engineers. I would be surprised if it didn't function properly with a major development framework, but YMMV.

Comment: Can I advise strongly against the idea of `start it in "non-clustered" mode`, you'll cause yourself no-end of headaches, especially if you're happy for your database to be down for a few minutes as you said. If you start one in non-clustered, import and then let the other join and take data from this one, what happens to the data the other recorded while this one was importing the old data? This is called a split-brain and you certainly don't want one. When you get one node to join the other, the joining one will sync with the doner and forget what it had itself, they will not merge data.